# Imprecise Chinese Remainder Theorem with Fractions

Tags: optimization, rational-numbers, chinese-remainder-theorem

I am familiar with how to use CRT on integers, but I have a case where I am operating on fractional values. For instance, say I have the equations

$$ x \equiv 6.8 \ \mathbf{mod} \ 10.1$$
$$ x \equiv 4.7 \ \mathbf{mod} \ 6.93$$

Is it possible to compute the smallest tolerance guaranteeing an answer before beginning the procedure? I.e. what is the smallest possible value of EPS in the code below? If EPS is too large I may miss a more precise solution.

```
EPS = 0.5 % some tolerance
x = 6.8;
while abs(mod(x, 6.93) - 4.7) > EPS
    if x >= 10.1*6.93
        sprintf('No solution.');
    end
    x = x + 10.1;
end
```

**Edit:** For the code above, the answer is $x=67.4$, since mod(67.4, 10.1) = 6.8 and mod(67.4, 6.93) = 5.03 which is within 0.5 of 4.7

I could iterate through $6.8, ..., n+10.1$ and return to the user the closest answer, but I was wondering if there was a way of predetermining that tolerance.

Comment: I've never seen modular arithmetic with decimal places. Is it just remainder after division?

Comment: What is the meaning of $\,x\equiv 6.8\bmod 10.1?\ \ $

Comment: Congruence. Basically $x = 10.1*M + 6.8$ where M is some integer (Hence the repeated addition in the while loop. The addition functions as incrementing $M$)

Comment: @RubenduBurck Yep, so mod(11, 10.1) = 0.9 for instance

Comment: What precision do we take the moduli to have?  This is equivalent to asking what moduli are we *really* using, scaled to match the nominal moduli?

Comment: @EricTowers I'm a little confused by your question, but the moduli should have more precision than the numbers in question. So it is accurate up to 64-bits of double subtraction precision (Matlab default -- that's where I'm using this)

Answer (score 1):

I would scale everything up to integers
so the system would be

$100x \equiv 680 \ \mathbf{mod} \ 1010\\
100x \equiv 470 \ \mathbf{mod} \ 693
$

There might not be
any solution because
of gcd restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Do you know if I can use this to see what tolerance I can get on my answer? Based on my situation I can guarantee both mod parameters (10.1, 6.93) are prime relative to each other

Comment: You can reduce the first to $-x\equiv 74 \bmod 101$

Comment: second reduces to $x\equiv 8\bmod 11$